# The number of years a election candidate has been active should also be weighed with candidate score

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, stack-exchange, candidate-score

First of all congratulations to the winners of 2020 Moderator Election. I think there is a minor flaw in the way we select moderators in StackExchange sites and I am not singling out stackoverflow alone.

I myself am a member of many sister SE sites and also generally participate in the election process of those sites as a voter. When selecting a candidate I primarily use the candidate score for my end decision and then only their self description because its **bolded**,easier and quantifiable. I believe many also do the same thing because of our innate psychological biases. Consider these two hypothetical SE active candidates with their name, membership years and candidate score,

```
Name    Years   Score
  A       5      40
  B       8      38
```

Because of our prejudices most voters are gonna select person A as their candidate because 40 being higher than 38. In my view we should consider both candidates equally with same candidate score. Having one or two points less than the opponent should not be considered as a shortcoming for experienced and active candidate.

Edited:

I already mentioned that I take part in the other SE's election process. I have seen a trend in those elections that candidates with highest candidate score are most likely to win as moderators. If it is obvious that the community selects the person with highest candidate score then what is the point of election itself. if community wants the highest scored individual then can't an algo itself select the best from the nominees without any elections.

Comment: What if the B candidate is missing the "Yearling" and "Constituent" badges? They just happened to create an account 8 years ago, but didn't start using it until recently.

Comment: Age is not a merit, it comes out of its own volition.

Comment: If anything, your hypothetical example shows that the candidate A should be preferred, as their ratio of candidate points per year is 8.0 across 5 years while candidate B has 4.75 across 8 years. As 20/40 points are awarded for reputation, it should also be taken into account, but not "years of service"

Comment: You know, it's perfectly possible to have a very high candidate score and lots of moderation experience, and only have been on the site a few months, and it's equivalently possible to have been on the site for a long time and have a low candidate score and little to no moderation experience. Weighting in age gives an unfair advantage to those who signed up 10 years ago, and who have barely or not at all contributed in terms of moderation. The current scoring system doesn't care about age and tries to highlight experience, and even then, you're not required to have a high candidate score to run

Comment: I think users downvoted because **age** in English normally refers to how old someone is. For example, **Joe Biden's age** is often viewed as a drawback to his candidacy. The US presidential candidate is 77 years old. P.S It would be interesting to know for certain, if the downvotes are just based on a summary reading of the title.

Comment: If you feel like it, edit the title (I do not have enough reputation to do it myself) and write: **The number of years a candidate has been active should also be weighed**

Comment: @Mari-LouA it says "membership age". It implies account age, not years since birth (... hopefully)

Comment: @Zoe when I first read the title, I was misled. I don't think I'm unique in this. But maybe I am. 31 downvotes seem a bit harsh to me, the idea is not so terrible as to merit that score.

Comment: @Mari-LouA People disagree - that's why it was downvoted. "not so terrible" is extremely subjective. I think it is - you apparently don't, and that's fine. This is meta, and disagreements on ideas happen pretty much constantly. Saying it doesn't deserve 31 downvotes is also subjective. Let's stop talking about votes and rather discuss the actual question rather than meta on a meta question that really doesn't need a meta discussion. Also, you misunderstanding something does **not** mean everyone else interpreted it in the exact same way

Comment: If you are really concerned about length of membership it is detailed in user profiles

Answer (score 12):

While I agree that some indicator for the continuity of moderation activity could be helpful, I don't think that the account age is a good metric: As @Scratte already noted in the comments, the account age doesn't tell us anything about the activity of the given candidate. They may have reached a candidate score of 40 five years ago, and then completely stopped contributing. This would probably be pointed out in the comments, but those are much less likely to be seen than the candidate score.

A better approach may be something like the reputation graph, but for moderation activity: This may indicate the number of reviews and/or close/delete votes per week.

Comment: The "Activity" tab in the user profile is also a good indicator.